# What happens if you say you're doing Adventurers League, but end up playing a completely home rule thing?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

A game shop near me hosts organised play. I've visited it to play Adventurers League.  The DM is instead playing a World of Warcraft adventure including variant rules like a mana system.  The game has nothing to do with AL, proper.

They are using actual D&D Adventurers League branding, including logos in the pamphlet and the publicity. The DM claims it's official, and when I tried to tell them it wasn't they insisted it was since, “[he] bought the world of warcraft D&D book”.

What can a player do? Can I call/write to the AL organizer and tell them that this event isn't really AL-official? Do I just stop going and look elsewhere? Do I ring up the D&D brass and tell them to slap the wrist of the DM in question?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Do I just stop going and look elsewhere?

Assuming that you want to play official AL games, then you should definitely do this. The shop you are visiting doesn't supply what you want so you have to go elsewhere if you want to play AL.

> Can I call/write to the AL organizer and tell them that this event isn't really AL-official?

I had a look through [the AL website](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play), including [the FAQ](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf) and couldn't see any recommendations on how to handle this.

It sounds like they have wasted your time, and taking some steps that might save other people the same bother could be worthwhile.

You've already spoken to the DM. If you're going to escalate it, then talk to the store owner next. (Thanks to [doppelgreener](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1204/doppelgreener) for pointing that out)

If that fails, then getting in touch with AL (e.g. through [customer services](https://dnd-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) to try to improve things. Note that it could hurt the store (which is why you should try to get the store to resolve it) so you should consider the effects there as well as on players.

---

[WotC have this to say](https://twitter.com/DnD_AdvLeague/status/1074663369079181312):

> It's worth talking to the store management and letting them know of
>   the issue, especially if they are reporting the games in their Wizards
>   Play Network information. If the DM persists, reach out to Wizards
>   customer service:
>
> https://dnd-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us/requests/new